# La terminal integrada de vscode abre en una ventana separada

Tags: windows, terminal, vscode

Después de una actualización de windows la terminal integrada de vscode abre en una ventana separada, he intentado de todo para que la terminal se ejecute en el panel inferior derecho como normalmente lo hacia pero no lo consigo. He utilizado lo que recomiendan aquí sin éxito:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474379/vscode-integrated-terminal-creates-a-separate-window

Debe ser algo relacionado con la actualización de windows.
Tengo vscode 1.36.0-insider en Windows 10.0.18362
Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar a vscode 1.36, y no he tenido el problema, ¿seria muy extremo desinstalarlo y volver a instalarlo?

Comment: Ya lo hize un par de veces con los mismos resultados, incluisve borre directorios y todo para que no quedaran datos previos de la instalación anterior

Comment: Encontré un solución temporal al problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154957/how-do-i-get-around-the-verified-bug-in-windows-1903-and-launch-the-vscode-integ